# GWT set caret position on content editable div

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm writing a web based code editor, where every line is a content editable div.
I wrote a native method to set caret position on a given index, but it works only in chrome. opera and firefox always sets caret on a beggining of a line.

```
public native void setCursorPos(int index) /*-{
    //console.log(index);
    var that = this.@edu.pg.client.CodeLine::getElement()();
    var position = index;
    var el = that;
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
            function(el) {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }, false);

    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        if (position - treeWalker.currentNode.length <= 0) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            console.log(position);
            range.setStart(treeWalker.currentNode, position);
            range.setEnd(treeWalker.currentNode, position);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
            el.focus();
            return;
        } else {
            position = position - treeWalker.currentNode.length;
        }
    }
```

while testing a code i was using this http://jsbin.com/EcETajo/5/edit
and it works in chrome, ff and opera.

is the function wrong or something on the gwt generated code changes caret position ?

EDIT: im using treewalker because i want to handle text hightlighting by wrapping text in span nodes in future

EDIT2: ok, ive found a problem by myself.

var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();

those lines were wrong. js code in gwt is in iframe, so to access my html elements i had to use something like this
                var range = $doc.createRange();
                var sel = $doc.getSelection();
wher $doc is a variable set by gwt

Comment: Please reply to your question with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proper use of document and window objects in gwt native method is by using $wnd and $doc that are set by gwt framework

Comment: Can you provide your solution for this? I try to get/set the caret position inside a `contenteditable` container.